# Property tag of struts2 using a properties file with html tags

Tags: struts2

I am migrating a Struts1 project to Struts2. It has a `properties` file with html tags like below.

#### properties file

```
profile.instruction.ordersearch=Enter the search criteria,and then click <b>Search</b>.
```

## Struts 1

#### jsp

```
<bean:message key="profile.instruction.ordersearch" />
```

#### Output

> Enter the search criteria,and then click **Search**.

## Struts 2

I replaced the bean tag with an `s:property` for Struts 2.

#### jsp

```
<s:property value="getText('profile.instruction.ordersearch')"/>
```

#### Output

```
Enter the search criteria,and then click <b>Search</b>.
```

As you can see, the "Search" text is not bold like in Struts 1 and is getting displayed with the tags. Is there a way to get the property tag to show it like struts 1 using the property tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the escapeHtml attribute in s:property tag to false: This should work.

```
<s:property escapeHtml="false" value="getText('profile.instruction.ordersearch')"/>
```